# Sending plain strings with ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I'm trying to send a plain string using an Ajax post request:

### jQuery

```
var user = {
    "name": name,
    "country": country,
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    url: 'Default.aspx/Submit',
    data: JSON.stringify(user),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (msg) {
      alert("Success!");
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("Error!");
    }
});
```

### ASP.NET

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool Submit(string json)
{
    // do something
    return true;
}
```

I set:

- traditional = true to avoid recursive encoding (not sure if needed)
- data is a `string`, not an `object`
- dataType is `text` not `json`

but I still got this error from server:

> invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: json

I guess this is because it doesn't find a matching name for the "json" parameter. But I don't understand how I have to name the function parameter if I'm sending a plain string.

Comment: It seems I have to set `contentType: "plain/text"`

Comment: do and check instead of telling

Comment: I've already done and checked. But to be sure I need to test it further. and I don't like to solve problems by random trials, instead I like to understand what I'm doing and learn from docs and from people more expert than me.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I use to post to a database using AJAX.

// Variable to hold request
var request;

// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#form1").submit(function(event){

```
// Abort any pending request
if (request) {
    request.abort();
}
//local variables
var $form = $(this);

// select and cache all the fields
var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

// Serialize the data in the form
var serializedData = $form.serialize();

// Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
// Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
// Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
$inputs.prop("disabled", true);

// Fire off the request to php file
request = $.ajax({
    url: yourdomain-asp-page,
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData
});

// Callback handler that will be called on success
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //replace form with feedback text


// Callback handler that will be called on failure
request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    // Log the error to the console
    console.error(
        "The following error occurred: "+
        textStatus, errorThrown
    );
});

// Callback handler that will be called regardless
// if the request failed or succeeded
request.always(function () {
    // Reenable the inputs
    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
});

// Prevent default posting of form
event.preventDefault();
```

});

Comment: It's an interesting way to send the form contents. In my specific case it's not applicable because I have to collect other data that is not directly accessible in the form controls.